# How can i get netbeans to work with cygwin compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, netbeans, compiler-errors

so i downloaded netbeans 8.02, jdk 64 bit. i then went on to download cygwin following the instructions offered on https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html

however after following all instructions, when i tested to see if the installation went well, my projects failed to build. can someone tell me if there is anything else i need to do please?

i am using windows 8 and netbeans for C++.

Comment: You should provide a bit more than just "it fails". Which errors, where, when?

Comment: on the netbeans instruction website, it says that i should build a sample project to test and verify that the compiler works. i do file, new project, samples, C/C++, then i choose the welcome project, then finish. when right click the welcome_1 project name and click build, the results comes out as, build failed (Directory C:\Users\${imba}\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Welcome_1 doesnt exist)

Comment: Means that the compiler does not work. Have you verified that it's installed correctly?

Comment: i do not know how to verify. the only thing that i think might the problem was when i was selecting the cygwin packages the versions that netbeans reccomended me to get were not in the cygwin installer.  for example, the installer reccomended me to get gcc and G++ 4.3.4 but the cygwin only offers version 4.8. im not sure if this is the problem